# How to solve "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph" error in scrbook document class?

Tags: tables, captions, koma-script

I am new to LaTeX, and trying to create a table in a document with scrbook document class. This document doesn't have any other content, but a table in first page itself. And when I compile, I am getting this error: "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph".

My code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,%font size 12
paper =a4,%a4 size paper
final,%final, not draft
twoside = semi,%print two side of the paper
openright,%open new chapter on right page
titlepage = firstiscover,
leqno,%equation number on left
fleqn, 
chapterprefix, %Write "Chapter" before chapter name
appendixprefix, %write "Appendix" before appendix name
headsepline, %horizontal line below header
footsepline, %horizontal line above footer
listof = nottotoc,%don't include list of table and list of figures in TOC
parskip = full,
captions = tableheading]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}%use British English
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setcaptionalignment{c}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \caption{\begin{center}
                My Introductory Table
        \end{center}}
                \label{tbl:sample}
                \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \hline
                Heading 1 & Heading 2\\
                \hline
                Item 1 & Item 2 \\
                Item 3 & Item 4 \\
                Item 5 & Item 6 \\
                Item 7 & Item 8\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

In the desired output, I want to keep both, all the tables and their respective captions in the center alignment. How can I do this?

Comment: Your title asks about a warning, but your example gives the error `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.` which means the pdf is not usable. You should not put formatting in the `\caption` (as it is used in multiple places with different formatting) you can specify elsewhere that captions are centred.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The posted code does not give an underful box warning, however it stops with an error due to the misplaced `center` inside the caption. If you delete that you still get a centred caption, and no error or warning.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,%font size 12
paper =a4,%a4 size paper
final,%final, not draft
twoside = semi,%print two side of the paper
openright,%open new chapter on right page
titlepage = firstiscover,
leqno,%equation number on left
fleqn, 
chapterprefix, %Write "Chapter" before chapter name
appendixprefix, %write "Appendix" before appendix name
headsepline, %horizontal line below header
footsepline, %horizontal line above footer
listof = nottotoc,%don't include list of table and list of figures in TOC
parskip = full,
captions = tableheading]{scrbook}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[british]{babel}%use British English
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setcaptionalignment{c}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
\begin{table}[htbp]
        \centering
        \caption{My Introductory Table}
                \label{tbl:sample}
                \begin{tabular}{cc}
                \hline
                Heading 1 & Heading 2\\
                \hline
                Item 1 & Item 2 \\
                Item 3 & Item 4 \\
                Item 5 & Item 6 \\
                Item 7 & Item 8\\
                \hline
            \end{tabular}
        \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In my TeXStudio, I am getting this warning: 5: Underfull \hbox (badness 10000) in paragraph. It is showing line 5, which reads "openright," in the document preamble. I don't think I have made any mistake there.

Comment: @Eva you can not get that warning from the preamble. It will be line 5 of a different document, I doubt you get that warning from the code you posted. Do as you asked us to do: start a new document with exactly the code copied from your question.

Comment: Thank you @David Carlisle for your support. I had to delete the other files (aux, bbl, etc.) in the folder. I just kept the .tex file in the folder, and when I compiled after that, it worked properly. I don't know what was wrong with the old files.